# How to add edit button in todo app in react native

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have just started learning react native this week and after watching some long youtube tutorials I decided to create a to do list app in which the person can add, delete and edit the generated list of things to do. Currently my code can just add and delete but I was wondering how can a edit function be added to my project, I have no idea of how to make that work so if anyone can help me with an idea on this it will be awesome. My Imagination Is When the User Clicks The Edit Button it should go back to the input and update it.

Here is a code of my project https://snack.expo.dev/3KJRAXHAn

Pls Help Me

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/F3SDRvhFC

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the todos array in a new variable (e.g., `const todosToEdit = todos`)
2. Iterate through the todos stored in the state (similar to the way you do in markTodosComplete() using the map function) to find the index of the todo you want to change
3. Replace the value at the index with the desired value (e.g., `todosToEdit[idx] = newValue`)
4. Store todosToEdit in the state (e.g., `setTodos(todosToEdit)`)